# Facebook login hacked; how to regain access to my account

Tags: facebook, account-recovery, hacked

I think my Facebook has been hacked as I can no longer log in. I no longer have the email associated with the Facebook .

I have tried to reset password by sending messages to friends and getting codes. Then prompted to change password. Facebook then says it sent a confirmation to the new email I entered however, I never receive the email. What else can I do to regain access to my Facebook account?

Answer (score 0):

[Report Compromised Account](https://www.facebook.com/hacked)
If you believe your account has been compromised by another person or a virus, please click the "My Account Is Compromised" button below. We'll help you log back into your account so that you can regain control.

For more details learn about [Hacked and Fake Accounts](https://www.facebook.com/help/hacked).